# What was the point of the life insurance plot?

Tags: plot-explanation, out-of-time

So, in *Out of Time* (2003) with Denzel as Mathias "Matt" Whitlock, what exactly is Anne's plan?

She fakes her sickness. Matt gives her the drug money. Then she sets Matt as the sole beneficiary of her life insurance, which results in a higher amount of money than the drug one. Then she fakes her and her husband's deaths, and tries to blame them on Matt.

So the plan is that all evidence leads to Matt and she has the drug money and needs to kill him because he is the only one who can realize what happened and trace her?

But why did she set her life insurance on Matt? Just to make another piece of evidence pointing to him?

She could have just faked her and her husband's deaths, set her friend, fake doctor, or anyone who wants as the sole beneficiary of her life insurance, and take the money and leave.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Sole Beneficiaries of a will are usually Suspect #1 in investigation cases.  It's most likely she wanted all the heat on Matt.

Comment: So you think the point of the movie was that Anne wanted Matt behind the bars ?
There is no motive to support that. I think it was all about the money. She planned to take Matt's drug money and blame her death on him. But what bothers me is that the methods she is using are illogical. If she wanted the money, she could have avoided taking the money from drug deal, fake her death, set Matt as the sole  beneficiary and split the money with him. Could have blamed it on her husband. In the movie, money from the life insurance is twice as much the drug money, so there is no point to waste it ..

Comment: Or I am not missing anything but the plot is just bad.
The movie is great in general though ..